# Multilevel block methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a view helper to render set of data in a format. I made these classes

```
require 'app/data_list/helper'

module App
  module DataList
    autoload :Builder, 'app/data_list/builder'
     @@data_list_tag = :ol
     @@list_tag      = :ul
    end
end
ActionView::Base.send :include, App::DataList::Helper
```

helper is

```
module App
  module DataList
    module Helper

      def data_list_for(object, html_options={}, &block)

        builder     = App::DataList::Builder
        arr_content = []
        object.each do |o|
          arr_content << capture(builder.new(o, self), &block)
        end
        content_tag(:ol, arr_content.join(" ").html_safe, html_options).html_safe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

builder is

```
require 'app/data_list/column'

module App
  module DataList
    class Builder
      include App::DataList::Column
      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

      attr_reader :object, :template

      def initialize(object, template)
        @object, @template = object, template
      end

      protected

      def wrap_list_item(name, value, options, &block)
        content_tag(:li, value).html_safe
      end

    end
  end
end
```

column module is

```
module App
  module DataList
    module Column
      def column(attribute_name, options={}, &block)
        collection_block, block = block, nil if block_given?

        puts attribute_name

        value = if block
                  block
                elsif @object.respond_to?(:"human_#{attribute_name}")
                  @object.send :"human_#{attribute_name}"
                else
                  @object.send(attribute_name)
                end

        wrap_list_item(attribute_name, value, options, &collection_block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now i write code to test it

```
 <%= data_list_for @contracts do |l| %>
        <%= l.column :age %>
        <%= l.column :contact do |c| %>
            <%= c.column :phones %>
        <% end %>
        <%= l.column :company %>
    <% end %>
```

Every thing is working fine , `age` , `contact` , `company` is working fine. But `phones` for the `contact` is not showing.

Does any one have an idea, i know i have missed something in the code. Looking for your help.

Updated question with complete source is [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562658/multi-level-block-method-is-generating-issue)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I can see in the column module.

1) If a block is provided you're setting it to nil - so `if block` is always returning false. 2) Even if `block` wasn't nil you're just returning the block as the value, not actually passing control to the block. You should be calling `block.call` or yielding. Implicit blocks execute faster, so I think your column module should look more like this:

```
module DataList
  module Column
    def column(attribute_name, options={})

      value = begin
        if block_given?
          yield self.class.new(@object.send(attribute_name), @template)
        elsif @object.respond_to?(:"human_#{attribute_name}")
          @object.send :"human_#{attribute_name}"
        else
          @object.send(attribute_name)
        end
      end

      wrap_list_item(attribute_name, value, options)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is generating some error. on line `<%= c.column :phones %>` it generates error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `column' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: Now error has changed `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `phones' for #<Lead:0xcfd6630>):`

Comment: Hm, how about `yield self.class.new(@object.send(attribute_name), @template)`? I'm assuming that the contacts that are being passed into `data_list_for` have a `contact` method which returns an object which will respond to `phones`?

Comment: Sorry to reply late. The change you suggested is working now... Hurraaa! But it also cause a small issue now, `:phones` are rendering but `:cotnact` do not render. I have to write extra line for it.

`<%= data_list_for @leads do |l| %>
        <%= l.column :age %>
        <%= l.column :contact %>
        <%= l.column :contact do |c| %>
            <%= c.column :phones %>
        <% end %>
        <%= l.column :company %>
    <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is now posted in the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562658/multi-level-block-method-is-generating-issue/5566126#5566126).