# Multi level block method is generating issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a class

```
class DataListBuilder
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    attr_accessor :object, :output_buffer

    def initialize(object)
      @object, @output_buffer = object, nil
    end

    def column (&block)
      if block_given?
        content_tag(:li, block.call(self))
      else
        content_tag(:li, "")
      end
    end

    def options_column(&link_block)
      if block_given?
        content_tag(:li, content_tag(:dl, "<dt><a href='#'>&nbsp;</a></dt><dd><ul>#{link_block.call(self)}</ul></dd>".html_safe, :class=>'options'))
      else
        content_tag(:li, "")
      end
    end

    def link_item(title, url, options={})
      content_tag :li, link_to(title, url, options)
    end
  end
```

and calling it as

```
<%= l.options_column do |c| %>
        <%= c.link_item 'Show', lead_path(c.object) %>
        <%= c.link_item 'Edit', edit_lead_path(c.object) %>
        <%= c.link_item 'New Note', "leads/#{c.object.id}/notes/new", :class=>"display-newxdoc", :id=>c.object.id %>
        <%= c.link_item 'Create Opportunity', new_lead_opportunity_path(c.object) %>
    <% end %>
```

the desired output is

```
<li><dl class="options"><dt><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></dt><dd><ul style="display: none;">
    <li><a data-remote="true" class="plus" href="leads/details/309">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li>3w</li>
    <li>Simon Wu</li>
    <li>1-714-553-0888</li>
    <li>omnisw@unifiedbeat.com</li>
    <li>Unified Beat</li>

        <li><a href="/leads/309">Show</a></li>
        <li><a href="/leads/309/edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a id="309" class="display-newxdoc" href="leads/309/notes/new">New Note</a></li>
        <li><a href="/leads/309/opportunities/new">Create Opportunity</a></li>
```

but it is generating

```
<li><a href="/leads/309">Show</a></li>
<li><a href="/leads/309/edit">Edit</a></li>
<li><a id="309" class="display-newxdoc" href="leads/309/notes/new">New Note</a></li>
<li><a href="/leads/309/opportunities/new">Create Opportunity</a></li>
<li><dl class="options"><dt><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></dt><dd><ul style="display: none;">
    <li><a data-remote="true" class="plus" href="leads/details/309">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li>3w</li>
    <li>Simon Wu</li>
    <li>1-714-553-0888</li>
    <li>omnisw@unifiedbeat.com</li>
    <li>Unified Beat</li>

        <li><a href="/leads/309">Show</a></li>
        <li><a href="/leads/309/edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a id="309" class="display-newxdoc" href="leads/309/notes/new">New Note</a></li>
        <li><a href="/leads/309/opportunities/new">Create Opportunity</a></li>
</ul></dd></dl></li>
    </ul></dd></dl></li>
```

Can any one help me in it.

Complete code is listed [here](https://gist.github.com/905258).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all we refactored your helper for more intensive usage of `content_tag` (just to get whats going in this code ^_^).

Next we add usage of `output_buffer` which was defined but not used at all in helper.

After it all methods wich should be called from `erb` should return `nil` so they didn't appear in HTML.

And last syntactic suger was usage of `instance_eval` so you don't need `{|c| ...}` style blocks. You can use all variables from `DataListBuilder` directly there.

```
module DataListHelper
  def list_headers(args=[])
    args    = Array.new(args)
    columns = []
    args.map { |o| columns << content_tag(:li, o.split(":").first, :style=>"width:#{o.split(":").second}px;") }
    content_tag(:ul, columns.join(" ").html_safe, :class=>"list-headers")
  end

  def data_list_total_records(array)
    content_tag(:div, page_entries_info(array).html_safe, :class=>"total-records")
  end

  def data_list_for(object, headers=[], &block)

    if object.is_a? Array
      if object.length == 0
        list_headers(headers).concat(content_tag(:strong, "<br />No records found".html_safe))
      else
        res_obj = data_list_total_records(object)
        res_obj << content_tag(:ol, :class=>"data-list") do
          res_ol = content_tag(:li) do
            res = list_headers(headers)
            object.each do |o|
              builder = DataListBuilder.new(o)
              res << content_tag(:li) do
                content_tag(:ul, :id=>o.id, :class=>"list-row #{cycle('odd', 'even')}") do
                  capture(builder, &block)
                  builder.output_buffer.html_safe
                end
              end
            end
            res
          end
          res_ol << data_list_pagination(object)
        end
        res_obj
      end
    else
      list_headers(headers).concat(content_tag(:strong, " <br />Not available."))
    end
  end

  class DataListBuilder
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    attr_accessor :object, :output_buffer, :controller

    def initialize(object)
      @object, @output_buffer = object, ''
    end

    def column (&block)
      @output_buffer << if block_given?
        content_tag(:li, instance_eval(&block))
      else
        content_tag(:li, "")
      end
      nil
    end

    def options_column(&link_block)
      @output_buffer << if block_given?
        content_tag(:li) do
          content_tag(:dl, :class=>'options') do
            res = content_tag(:dt) do
              content_tag(:a, '&nbsp;'.html_safe, :href => '#')
            end
            res << content_tag(:dd) do
              content_tag(:ul) do
                instance_eval &link_block
              end
            end
          end
        end
      else
        content_tag(:li, "")
      end
      nil
    end

    def link_item(title, url, options={})
      content_tag :li, link_to(title, url, options)
    end
  end
end
```

And your view became this:

```
<%= data_list_for @leads, [" :10", "Age:30", "Contact:140", "Phone:140", "Email:180", "Company:100", ""] do |l| %>
    <%= l.column { link_to "&nbsp;".html_safe, "leads/details/#{object.id}", :class=>:plus, :remote=>true } %>
    <%= l.column { object.age } %>
    <%= l.column { object.contact.complete_name } %>
    <%= l.column { object.contact.phones.blank? ? "-" : object.contact.phones.first.phone_number } %>
    <%= l.column { object.contact.emails.blank? ? "-" : object.contact.emails.first.email } %>
    <%= l.column { object.company.title } %>
    <%= l.options_column do %>
        <%= link_item 'Show', lead_path(object.id) %>
        <%= link_item 'Edit', edit_lead_path(object.id) %>
        <%= link_item 'New Note', "leads/#{object.id}/notes/new", :class=>"display-newxdoc", :id=>object.id %>
        <%= link_item 'Create Opportunity', new_lead_opportunity_path(object.id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Really really really thanks. It works. and it also gave me complete insight of what is going on and inside. Now the only issue remains is that `lead_path(object)` and route methods are not working. It generates errors `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `lead_path' for #<DataListHelper::DataListBuilder:0xef8c3bc>):`.

This is the only thing remains in the list. Please help to solve it.

Comment: @Nazar Huaain - I updated answer to solve your issue with links. Added `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` and attribute `controller` into `DataListBuilder`. Added `object.id` into view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models/5456103#5456103 for more info

Answer (score 0):

`options_column` is a "block view", I'd remove the = in `<%= l.options_column do |c| %>`, that's for sure. Then, I'd use `concat` in `options_column` instead of returning it directly as a string.

Anyway, the simple solution is here (I've used it, no problems at all):

https://github.com/markevans/block_helpers

Comment: It is really great. but i have question for it. How can we make such block helpers who iterate on the some collection. I can not found any example or way on the wiki of the helper you suggested. Please send me any example for it.